# How can I figure out how many anagrams of oranwawoods contain at least two consecutive o’s?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I figure out how many anagrams of oranwawoods contain at least two consecutive o’s?.Because we can let two o's be x, and there are 9 letters left, and in the rest of 9 letters, we have 2a and 2w, so number of anagrams is:
$$\frac{9! }{2! \times 2!}$$. Am I correct? Thank you

Comment: Looks like you want a word of length 10, but that isn't specified anywhere. Also, the title is not part of the question; it's a title that describes the question. Have the entire question located in the body of the question.

Comment: I want a word of length 11, but need to find how many anagrams of oranwawoods contain at least two consecutive o’s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer is

$$\frac{10!}{2! \times 2!} - \frac{9!}{2!\times 2!}.$$

The 1st term reflects that when $2$ of the $3$ o's are **fused** to together into $1$ unit, the $11$ letters have been converted into $10$ units to permute.

The 2nd term is an over counting adjustment term, that reflects that there are $3$ o's, rather than $2$.  That is, consider the sequence where the first $3$ characters are all o's.  This is counted twice, once when the fused pair is in positions $1-2$ and once when the fused pair is in positions $2-3$.

So, you have to deduct the number of words formed by $3$ consecutive o's.